# Cannot serialize dictionary to JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have this JSON

```
import json
f={'file_id': '2019_08_02_12_05_30.893834.csv', 'file_rows': [[b'Borough,OnStreet,CrossStreetOne,CrossStreetTwo,Asset\r\n'], [b'Brooklyn,Hoyt Street,Schermerhorn Street,Livingston Street,CityBench\r\n'], [b'Manhattan,HUDSON ST,BROOME ST,DOMINICK ST,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Manhattan,HUDSON ST,CHARLTON ST,KING ST,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Manhattan,HUDSON ST,CHARLTON ST,KING ST,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Manhattan,HUDSON ST,KING ST,W HOUSTON ST,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Manhattan,HUDSON ST,SPRING ST,VAN DAM ST,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Bronx,CROSS BRONX EP,HUGH J GRANT CI,VIRGINIA AV,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Brooklyn,JACKSON ST,HUMBOLDT ST,WOODPOINT RD,Bike Rack\r\n']]}

print(json.dumps(f.decode('utf-8')))
```

gives me this error

```
print(json.dumps(f.decode('utf-8')))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

following this advice

[Convert bytes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

what do I need to do here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `default=` parameter ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.dump)), where you decode bytes object from `utf-8` (function specified in `decode=` parameter gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized):

```
import json
f={'file_id': '2019_08_02_12_05_30.893834.csv', 'file_rows': [[b'Borough,OnStreet,CrossStreetOne,CrossStreetTwo,Asset\r\n'], [b'Brooklyn,Hoyt Street,Schermerhorn Street,Livingston Street,CityBench\r\n'], [b'Manhattan,HUDSON ST,BROOME ST,DOMINICK ST,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Manhattan,HUDSON ST,CHARLTON ST,KING ST,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Manhattan,HUDSON ST,CHARLTON ST,KING ST,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Manhattan,HUDSON ST,KING ST,W HOUSTON ST,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Manhattan,HUDSON ST,SPRING ST,VAN DAM ST,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Bronx,CROSS BRONX EP,HUGH J GRANT CI,VIRGINIA AV,Bike Rack\r\n'], [b'Brooklyn,JACKSON ST,HUMBOLDT ST,WOODPOINT RD,Bike Rack\r\n']]}

def decode_bytes(o):
    return o.decode('utf-8')

print(json.dumps(f, default=decode_bytes, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "file_id": "2019_08_02_12_05_30.893834.csv",
    "file_rows": [
        [
            "Borough,OnStreet,CrossStreetOne,CrossStreetTwo,Asset\r\n"
        ],
        [
            "Brooklyn,Hoyt Street,Schermerhorn Street,Livingston Street,CityBench\r\n"
        ],
        [
            "Manhattan,HUDSON ST,BROOME ST,DOMINICK ST,Bike Rack\r\n"
        ],
        [
            "Manhattan,HUDSON ST,CHARLTON ST,KING ST,Bike Rack\r\n"
        ],
        [
            "Manhattan,HUDSON ST,CHARLTON ST,KING ST,Bike Rack\r\n"
        ],
        [
            "Manhattan,HUDSON ST,KING ST,W HOUSTON ST,Bike Rack\r\n"
        ],
        [
            "Manhattan,HUDSON ST,SPRING ST,VAN DAM ST,Bike Rack\r\n"
        ],
        [
            "Bronx,CROSS BRONX EP,HUGH J GRANT CI,VIRGINIA AV,Bike Rack\r\n"
        ],
        [
            "Brooklyn,JACKSON ST,HUMBOLDT ST,WOODPOINT RD,Bike Rack\r\n"
        ]
    ]
}
```